# Azure REST API Returns 200 for me and 203 for other users

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm creating an app and need the information about the user projects. When I request that for me, a administrator in the organization, the request goes without a problem. When other users request something it gives the 203 code.

I'm using the following code:

```
  var personalaccesstoken = token;

            using var client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
                Convert.ToBase64String(
                    Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                       $@"{""}:{personalaccesstoken}")));
             using var response = await client.GetAsync(
                "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/projects?api-version=2.0");
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

I'm using Oauth to get the token.
Does anyone know why this is not working?

Comment: 203 is still a success code. Why do you assume it's not working?

Comment: What do you mean by saying user? Do you use the same PAT token?

Answer (score 0):

The 203 error code normally caused by an **incorrect PAT format**. Looks like you are probably failing authentication because the PAT did not be encoded with `base64` correctly.

You need to ask the users to check the PAT in their code to see whether it is correct, or generate a new PAT and replace it in the code to see whether the issue would be fixed.